# D3.js: How can I tell apart JSON data from JSON file/endpoint

Tags: d3.js

I'd like for a function to be able to visualize a graph given either a path to a JSON file, or given JSON data directly. Is there a standard way of doing that? What I can think of right now would be to parse the parameter, and if it ends in ".json", pass it to d3.json(), else pass the data directly to graph.data().

Or maybe do something with error?

e.g.

```
d3.json(data, function(error,data){

    if (error)
       //bind data directly

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you have the following situation:

You have a function

```
function draw_graph(data) {
  // whatever you need to do to draw the graph
}
```

and then

```
function maybe_xhr_and_then_draw_or_just_draw(path_or_data) {
  if(is_remote(path_or_data)) {
    d3.json(path_or_data, draw_graph)
  } else {
    draw_graph(path_or_data)
  }
}
```

And the question is "what does `is_remote` look like?"

If I've got this right, then you are essentially asking how to type sniff, which is a dubious idea in a language like javascript, (see [here](http://calculist.org/tags/nominal-types.html) for why).

If you insist, then you can do:

```
function is_remote(path_or_data) {
  return !(path_or_data instanceof Object)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer!